# Bitcoin transaction fees and how to handle it

Tags: transactions, blockchain, transaction-fees

Lets say I set a very low transaction fee for a bitcoin transaction(from one of my own wallets to another). I also have mining equipment which is mining for bitcoins. Is there anyway to get that transaction request directed towards me ? In other words can I process my own transactions by giving it priority?
If so how do I do this?

Comment: Please ask one question per post; otherwise it gets very hard to keep straight what is answered and what hasn't.  I'm going to take the liberty of commenting out your second question; feel free to [ask a new question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) with it.  You can get the text by viewing the [edit history](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/posts/60746/revisions).

Comment: While you can prioritize your own transaction, it won't do much good, unless you're in control of a large hash pool. The probability of a single user ever completing a block specifically crafted with their own transaction is extremely small.  It is better to just pay a reasonable transaction fee.

Comment: If I want to send 10USD worth of bitcoins, I have to pay 6USD as fees?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can. This is the exact purpose of the RPC command [`prioritisetransaction`](https://chainquery.com/bitcoin-api/prioritisetransaction).